# Retrieving posts with latest 2 comments of each post in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a separate post table and a comment table. I am fetching 15 posts (pagination) and along with posts I want to fetch the latest 2 comments of each post. is there any efficient way to do so in a single or less Postgres-sql queries.

Post table - id, text, pics, likes, ownerId

Comment table - id, text, userId, postId

User table - id, profilePic, username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you want would seem to be:

```
select p.*, c.*
from post p left join
     (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by postid order by id desc) as seqnum
      from comments c
     ) c
     on p.postid = c.postid and seqnum <= 2
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. thanks man, I need one more suggestion, however, is it a correct way if I save id of recent comments (5) in post table. cause I also need to make comments array for each post when I send the response, and above way I would have to manipulate data on controller.

Comment: @YashOjha . . . You can use aggregation to construct an array or JSON array with the information you need.  If you need more details, I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.